# To find significant differences between means using repeated measures GLM

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, linear-model

I am new in using SPSS and stuck with General Linear Model [which is just linear model] procedure.

I have 8 cognition variables like latency, thigmotaxis, spatial, quadrant, nt quadrant, proximity, proximity nt and active speed. All these were analysed on day 1,2,3,4 and 5 And were tested for four different diet groups and only one gender (female). My boss wants to find the significant differences in means between the days and among diets and represent it as a table using GLM. I tried with just one variable using the GLM repeated measures but I don't know which p value must be reported.

I know so far that we have to go Analyse> general linear model> repeated measures> within-subject (entered as time)> levels (entered as 5)> define> within-subject variables (chosen for all days)> between-subjects (entered diet)> contrasts(repeated)> options(emmeans)> ok.

**I still don't understand how p values were obtained as shown in the image below**. I didn't see a table that shows like this or something similar to this. I don't know what I am missing here.  My data is in Means +/- SEM and N.

[image]

Comment: There is no such a menu in SPSS `Analyse> generalized linear model> repeated measures`. Are you speaking of general linear model?

Comment: What is your dependent variable here? EG, is it continuous or yes / no?

Comment: Sorry. Its Analyse > general linear model> repeated measures.. Yes its about general linear model. Dependent variable is the diet which is classified into 4 groups (Control, MSG, TFA, ASP).

Comment: The p-values should be the contrast comparisons between control and Day #. Take a look at the contrast settings and its output.

Comment: I set time as within-subject variable and level as five. Between-subject as diet. In contrast settings, for time i set repeated and for diet as simple. Is this right?

Comment: Do you want a table per diet? or what is it exactly that you want to calculate?

Comment: My boss wants to compare significant difference between means for all variables among day 1,2,3,4 and 5 with respect to all diets, using repeated measures GLM. And she told it will look like the image I gave above. However that is only between two groups (Control and ASP). :( I am totally new in this area. I do know about ANOVA, Pearson correlation, in an intermediate level. But with repeated measures GLM I am getting totally confused!!!!